# Using Ember data with D3.js nodes (Force Layout)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js

I want to link x and y attributes of nodes with my Ember.js Model.

```
    var nodes = this.get('store').findAll('node').then(function (nodes) {
            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("cx", function (d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .attr("r", 7)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return fill(1);
                    })
                    .style("stroke", function (d, i) {
                        return d3.rgb(fill(i)).darker(2);
                    });
    });
```

But I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` error in the console. I have x and y value defined in the model. Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong.

Basically all I want to do is use the x and y values from the model in the d3 plot.

Comment: If you `console.log(nodes)` before `var node`, what happens?

Comment: `Class {__ember1468380916865: "ember1081", __ember_meta__: Meta}` is logged in the console.

Comment: So, you don't have the data.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to get all the records and use it as an array but I can iterate on the records using a helper function. Is there a way to add nodes one by one? instead of using .data().enter()?

Comment: Yes, but it makes no sense. And you don't have *any* data right now.

Comment: That's because `this.get('store').findAll('node')` doesn't return a JavaScript array It is an object that implements Ember.Enumerable.

Comment: May be something like this using map: `var nodes = this.get('store').findAll('node').map(function(d){return d;})`

Answer (score 0):

`DS.Store.findAll` returns a promise, you will have to wait for it to resolve before using it.

```
this.get('store')
  .findAll('node')
  .then(nodes => {
    let node = svg.selectAll(".node") // rest of your code
  })
```

You will also need to use [Ember.get](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_get) to access the properties defined on the model

Comment: I've already tried this method but it didn't work. I'm getting the same error and when I try to log the var nodes it doesn't log array of items. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose d3 chart required format is `[{'x':'xvalue','y':'yvalue'}]`. then you need transform nodes result to new array of objects..

```
var d3ExpectedFormat = nodes.map(function(node){
 return {'x':node.get('x'),'y':node.get('y')};
});
```

instead of `.data(nodes)` try `.data(d3ExpectedFormat)`